# number_format(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type float

Tags: php, laravel

When I add this code to my blade. It displays and shows an array.

['2600000']

['4500000']

```
@foreach($amazings as $product)
    {{ number_format($product->prices->pluck('value')) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My question is this. How to show like this 260,000

Comment: Your product seems to have multiple prices. Assuming this is on purpose you need to decide which price you want to be showing or iterate through all of them.

Comment: I want to be showing price all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluck will still return a collection. You'd need to iterate through it, either with another foreach loop, or such as through map, etc:

```
@foreach($amazings as $product)
    @foreach($product->prices->pluck('value')->all() as $val)
        {{ number_format($val) }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

make the value $num float then pass that to that function.
Use **floatval($num)**
See documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: I see this error `Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to float`